# How to await a function in a normal function

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py, tweepy

In the following code I'll receive Tweets from the Twitter API over Tweepy. I want to send these Tweets in a Discord channel, but how can I work with an await function in a normal class.

```
import discord
import tweepy 

class Client(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('ready')

class TweepyStream(tweepy.Stream):
    def on_connect(self):
        print('connceted')

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)
        #How can I here send a message into a discord channel ?


stream = TweepyStream(keys)
stream.filter(follow = [],  threaded=True)

client = Client()
client.run(token)
```

Comment: I would personally send a event using `bot.dispatch()` then do what you have to do then

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use an [`asyncio.Task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) to run the coroutine.

Comment: "Use X" is more of a comment. If you are answering a question, you should include an example or some context so that your post answers the question fully.

Comment: But when i want to send a message 'await channel.send(message)' it doesnt work it gives me the error:
'RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task' What do i have to do now ?

Comment: Are you using a new event loop? You should use the existing event loop.